# Celluloid::TimeoutError: linking timeout of 5 seconds exceeded

Tags: ruby, actor, celluloid

I'm working with Jruby 1.7.12 and Celluloid (0.16.0). My application is using pools and generates actors in a loop

```
require 'kaiwa'
Kaiwa::Launcher.run
Celluloid.logger = Kaiwa::Logger.logger

class KaiwaTest
  include Celluloid
  Celluloid::LINKING_TIMEOUT = 5

  def initialize
  end

  def create_kaiwa_users(handle)
    Kaiwa::Manager.create_user(handle)
  end

 def send_kaiwa_messages(to_handle, from_handle, message)
   Kaiwa::Manager.send_message(to_handle, from_handle, message)
 end
end

kt = KaiwaTest.pool(size: 4)

(0..1_00_000).to_a.each do |index|
  kaiwa_test_pool.async.create_kaiwa_users("user_#{index}") 
 end
```

Within my library each user is an actor which gets linked to the manager, which is also an actor. I've tried eliminating the linking altogether and the problem still persists. The minute i create more than 30 user actors my system hangs.

There seems to be some similar timeout errors discussed with a mention of a JRuby issue but nothing that specifically touches the linking timeout issue. I cannot figure out what is causing the issue.

Thanks in advance.

The entire codebase is available at https://github.com/supersid/kaiwa

Would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting project ( XMPP +Celluloid +jRuby )

I'm assuming `kaiwa_test_pool` ought to be `kt`?

I would give this a try using `0.17.0`:

- https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/wiki/0.17.0-Prerelease

You do not need a `Pool` here. You just need a specialized `Supervision::Container`

What you need to do is instantiate a Manager, using `Kaiwa::Manager.supervise as: :manager`

Then instantiate a supervision container for your user actors.

Not sure why you create `0..1_00_000` users?

Either way, no `Pool` needed, use `0.17.0` and use a plain supervision container.